# Manipulate/copy dataframe (pandas) and maintain only the last day of each month

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `dt`:

```
           date  USDBRL
0    2000-01-03  1.8011
1    2000-01-04  1.8337
2    2000-01-05  1.8544
3    2000-01-06  1.8461
4    2000-01-07  1.8281
        ...     ...
5212 2020-10-01  5.6441
5213 2020-10-02  5.6464
5214 2020-10-05  5.6299
5215 2020-10-06  5.5205
5216 2020-10-07  5.6018
```

How can I manipulate this `dt`, or create a new one, containing only the rows with the last day of each month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dt.to_periods('M')` to find the month, then `duplicated` to find where they're duplicated, then boolean indexing:

```
months = pd.to_datetime(dt['date']).dt.to_period('M')

out = dt.loc[months.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Another approach is `groupby().idxmax()`. This is a bit slower but safer in the case your data is not sorted by `date`:

```
out = df.loc[df.groupby(months)['date'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: I'm trying to make the exact same change, but instead of manipulating a column ['date'], I'm trying to manipulate a datetime index. The first change I did was this one:

`months = pd.to_datetime(dt.index).to_period('M')`

The other codeline:

`out = df.loc[df.groupby(months)['date'].idxmax()]`

I could not solve!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of range of dates using `pd.date_range`. This is an alternative way

```py
required_datelist = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=12, freq='M')
output = dt[dt.date.isin(required_datelist)]
```